# Image heavy MainActivity lags on Samsung GS7 but not ancient phone

Tags: android, imageview

My main activity has a layout composed mostly of images used as buttons. The images are scaled down to their appropriate size using a `Percent Relative Layout`

The images themselves are .png files in my drawable folder. They're about 120 - 140kb each in what I'm assuming is their compressed format.

I thought this had to do with just too many images on the screen at once, but was curious to find that when loaded on a 3 year old device with a screen a fraction of the size of my Samsung GS7, it worked with minimal lag. The logcat even spit barely any frame rate skips.

Current theory is that perhaps the higher resolution screen is pulling more resources, but the memory on the GS7 should dwarf the old device.

And as an aside - the emulator runs like garbage. 100x slower than any physical devices so I don't bother with it.

Programatically, the only thing going on is an `onClickListener` for each `ImageView`. No other work is being done on the page.

**XML**

```
        <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="@string/abc"
                android:textSize="27sp"
                android:id="@+id/textMainTitle"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="def"
                android:id="@+id/textMainSubTitle"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_below="@id/textMainTitle"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/btn1"
                android:src="@drawable/1"
                app:layout_widthPercent="33%"
                android:layout_below="@id/textMainSubTitle"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/btn2"
                android:src="@drawable/2"
                app:layout_widthPercent="33%"
                android:layout_below="@id/textMainSubTitle"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/btn3"
                android:src="@drawable/3"
                app:layout_widthPercent="33%"
                android:layout_below="@id/textMainSubTitle"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn2"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                />

 // Other buttons removed. But there are six rows each with
 // 3 button as there are above
```

**Relevant Java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        btn1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), activity1.class));
            }
        });

        btn2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), activity2.class));
            }
        });

        btn3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
        btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), activity2.class));
            }
        });

 //As in the XML layout, all other buttons have been removed for visual
```

**Logcat**

```
I/Choreographer: Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/Choreographer: Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

//and so on.
```

Any advice or assistance is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Thanks all for your response. I got pulled away but I will come back and upvote/comment/mark asap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading all those images on the main thread is bad. You should load them asynchronously. Use an image loading library like [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso). They're usually used to download and display images from a remote source, but they can also handle local async loading wonderfully.

Let's do an async image load for your `btn1`. Using Glide (because it's my favourite), it couldn't be easier:

`Glide.with(this)  //  any Context subclass, depending on lifecycle needs
     .load(R.drawable.1)
     .into(btn1)`

Do this for all your `ImageViews` and you're golden. Don't forget to remove the `android:src = ...` xml attributes.

As for emulator sluggishness, if you're on Windows and an Intel CPU that supports VT, download and install the "Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)" from the SDK manager. Make sure VT-x is enabled in your BIOS.

Comment: I need to read more on how this works as I really don't understand it. But it  worked. For documentation for later readers: Installed Glide into my Gradle directly and updated my ProGuard with the specified settings. Used to Java code listed in this answer for all buttons and lag vanished :) Thanks a ton! I'd give you more upvotes if I had them!

Answer (score 0):

This is the reason why it's a bad idea to load images on the Main thread. The screen will lag (or skip frames). Image size of 120kb (each) is too much considering the number of images your loading.

Save the images on your server and retrieve them using an Async Task.

Answer (score 0):

```
 startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), activity1.class));

to 

 startActivity(new Intent(ActivityName.this, activity1.class));
```

//Do the Same with other two activities !

Comment: Hi, as a curiosity, why are you suggesting this?